# Vimperator pass-through/unset <C-Tab> by default

Tags: plugins, mru, vimperator

By default  is mapped to gt command, which selects next tab. I want to pass-through  to Crtl+Tab plugin which does MRU for tabs.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to pass-through, use:

`:map <C-Tab> i<C-Tab>`

Answer (score 1):

you can map C-Tab to gt command and, maybe, Control-Shift-Tab to gT command.

```
:inoremap <C-Tab> gt
:inoremap <C-S-Tab> gT
```

save your vimperatorrc with :mkvimperatorrc!

Answer (score -1):

1) Use [pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/) instead of vimperator. (pentadactyl is a fork of vimperator)
2) put in ~/_pentadactylrc the following:

```
nm <C-Tab> <Pass>
nm <C-S-Tab> <Pass>
```

Then pentadactyl will pass these events directly to Firefox.

Comment: and `:mkpentadactylrc` will save them (add an `!` to the end to overwrite existing)

Comment: do these work in insert mode? I think they only work in normal mode

Comment: In my experience, pentadactyl stops working everytime FF updates, which is why I switched to vimperator in the first place.